# Override plugin convention property with project property

Tags: gradle

I am trying to understand how to set a plugin convention property from a project property.

Here is the customPluginWithConvention example from the gradle distribution (gradle-0.9.2\samples\userguide\organizeBuildLogic\customPluginWithConvention\build.gradle)

```
apply plugin: GreetingPlugin

greeting = 'Hi from Gradle'

class GreetingPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    def void apply(Project project) {
        project.convention.plugins.greet = new GreetingPluginConvention()
        project.task('hello') << {
            println project.convention.plugins.greet.greeting
        }
    }
}

class GreetingPluginConvention {
    def String greeting = 'Hello from GreetingPlugin'
}
```

Running this script with no project property:

```
>gradle hello
:hello
Hi from Gradle

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

And now trying to set a custom message via setting a project property:

```
>gradle -Pgreeting=goodbye hello
:hello
Hello from GreetingPlugin
```

Instead of the expected "goodbye" the default greeting of the convention is shown. Is it possible to override the message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to override the message?

Not yet, but we should try to make it possible. Please create an issue at http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRADLE.